# General conditions for submatrices in regards to determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What are the most general conditions on sub-matrices A,B,C,D st

det[A B;C D] = det(AD-BC)

Obviously this is how determinant is defined for a regular square 2x2 matrix, but I don't understand how to incorporate sub-matrices.

Comment: The most general condition for a statement is always this statement itself. If you are looking for *nice* conditions, there are of course the commutativity conditions from [John R. Silvester, *Determinants of block matrices*](http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/new/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf). I don't think any more general sufficient conditions are known.

Answer (score 2):

Note that when $A$ is invertible, we have $$\begin{bmatrix}A & B \\ C & D\end{bmatrix}\,=\,\det(A)\det(D-CA^{-1}B) =\det(AD-ACA^{-1}B)$$ See this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) for more. So, if $C=I$ or $C$ commutes with $A$ or $A^{-1}$, you will have your required result. From the same wiki page, you can derive a similar result when $D$ is invertible.